# PAM Faulty Module

Tags: centos, pam

After updating PAM secure log started showing:

```
su: PAM unable to dlopen(/lib64/security/pam_rootok.so): /lib64/security/pam_rootok.so: undefined symbol: selinux_check_access
su: PAM adding faulty module: /lib64/security/pam_rootok.so
```

Given the name of the file this seems like a serious concern, but I can't find any information about the error. I don't let anyone log onto this server so I'm not trying to protect against local users, but I still want PAM to work properly against anyone who has gained unauthorized access.

Edit: pam_rootok.so does exist and its permissions are the same as the other files under `/lib64/security`. Also `su` seems to work since I can still move from non-root users to root.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key bit of the error is

```
undefined symbol: selinux_check_access
```

This symbol should be in `/lib64/libselinux.so.1`.  You might want to check that file is present, readable and has a good checksum.

Comment: Thanks, the file does exist with proper permissions. I understand checksums, but what's a good way to find the correct checksum for that file?

Comment: I'll leave that for someone who knows centos... might also be worth checking the output of `ldd /lib64/security/pam_rootok.so` to see what libraries it loads dynamically in case it's looking elsewhere.

Comment: You can `yum provides /lib64/libselinux.so.1` to find the package providing this file then `rpm -V <packagename>` to verify the package. If SELinux is enabled, make sure it is not denying access to the file, etc.

Comment: @AaronCopley: Thanks, that's good information to get me started.